# Can/Should a http read_timeout be retried?

Tags: ruby, http, language-agnostic, timeout

I'm on a network that usually causes a ton of connection timeout issues, and ocasionally I'm running into read timeout issues as well. Retrying the code whenever a connect timeout happens fixes the problem with connecting to the server. Is is safe to retry the code whenever I get a read_timeout, or whould the response become corrupted? I'm using Ruby, with Net::HTTP client, but I guess this could apply to other languages as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A read_timeout means that the server did not send any data within the expected timeout. The response becoming corrupted is less likely as this is TCP.

To answer if it's safe or not to retry depends on what operation you're performing and/or any guarantees the service you're interacting with gives you.

In general GET should be safe to retry. 
POST/PUT may need special handling (i.e. rereading some state before deciding to retry) as this usually means that something changes on the server.